# Which is the correct behavior of the struct with unnamed member in C99 language?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, struct, c99

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {int;};

int main()
{
    printf("Size of 'struct s': %i\n", sizeof(struct s));    
    return 0;
}
```

Microsoft C compiler (cl.exe) does not want compile this code.

```
error C2208: 'int' : no members defined using this type
```

GNU C compiler (gcc -std=c99) compiles this code...

```
warning: declaration does not declare anything
```

...and displays the result:

```
Size of 'struct s': 0
```

This means that `struct s` in gcc are complete type and cannot be redefined.
Does this means that the complete type can have zero size?

Also, what means the message `declaration does not declare anything` if this declaration declares the complete struct?

Here is the proof that the `struct s` is a complete type in (gcc -std=c99).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {int;};

struct S {
    struct s s; // <=========== No problem to use it
};

int main()
{
    printf("Size of 'struct s': %i\n", sizeof(struct s));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is a feature of gcc,  but not a feature of c99

Comment: @VolAnd. Thanks. This is because for me is not understandable the term `undefined behavior` in language specifctions. Undefined behavior at runtime or undefined behavior at compile time.

Comment: "warning: declaration does not declare anything" is about compile time. Undefined behavior is about runtime.

Comment: @VolAnd Er, no. Undefined behavior just means the standard imposes no requirements.

Comment: I'm agree, it is impossible to write requirements for incorrect usage of language. But for me, personally, "undefined behavior" is rather about programs written as "bad programming examples" than about compilers that do anything with "bad programming examples"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is undefined as per C standard.

#### J.2 Undefined behavior:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>   ....
>   — **A structure or union is defined without any named members** (including those specified indirectly via anonymous structures and unions) (6.7.2.1).

`struct s {int;};` is equivalent to `struct s {};` (no members) and GCC allows this as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html).

> ```
> struct empty {
>
> };
> ```
>
> The structure has size zero.

This makes the above program a compiler specific.

Comment: OK. The behavior is undefined for the struct behavior or for the compiler behavior? No problem but why MS C compiler does not want compile code with the undefined behavior. What behavior is better? MSVC or GCC?

Comment: @mezoni; Result would be compiler specific in this case.

Comment: Thank! Add this to the answer to the completeness.

Answer (score 2):

A type with size 0 is not standard.  That is a gcc extension.

If you add -pedantic-errors to your gcc compile line, then it won't compile.

Comment: Hmmm, surprisingly gcc still compiles for me even with -ansi -pedantic.

Comment: @mezoni The only way to force a guaranteed compiler error is `-pedantic-errors`. By the way, `-ansi` just means C89/90.